# Plotting a parametric function that is highly nonlinear

Tags: parametric-functions, nonlinear

Okay, so I'm having some trouble with some very badly behaved functions. I'll try to phrase the question in general terms to begin with, because the actual equations consist of about 12 numerical parameters each, plus I coded it very poorly by writing parameter names with subscripts and such (which I won't do again..) so copy pasting it looks horrendous and takes quite some time to fix, but if needed I can definitely do it. However, I believe that I can explain and illustrate the issue quite clearly, so perhaps some general methods of fixing this can be thought of.

So, lets start. I have two functions, $V(t)$ and $I(t)$, and I was to plot $I$ versus $V$. So it's a parametric plot problem. Now, what I want to do is plot in a certain region, $V \in [0,2]$. $V(t)$, however, is a rather nonlinear function. It reaches the value $V(t) = 2$ at about $t = 0.01$, then goes to say $V(t) = 1.5$ at $t = 0.2$, and then the trouble starts. Because at this point, $V(t)$ starts to become *very* slowly changing: it won't reach $V(t) = 0$ until $t = 10^{21}$.

So, this is giving me issues when plotting. If I plot the full thing from $t = 0$ to $t = 10^{21}$, it doesn't look remotely correct. I suppose this is because ParametricPlot tries to interpolate, and fails, because it is such a horrible function. What would be a solution to this?

One thing I have done myself is cut the function into multiple pieces. Taking four ranges of t, I get the following four figures (you can ignore the axes and the fact that there are two curves, they behave similarly as you can see)
[image]

So in this way I can see that ParametricPlot is definitely able to resolve the regions piece by piece (as I am reproducing figures from a paper I know this is correct), but just not all at once. That's what I'm trying to do, and I was wondering if you have any advice. One way perhaps would be to use Show to combine the different regions, but that seems a bit dirty.

Also, as an aside, I am now plotting directly in terms of t. But if I already know the range in which I want to plot my x-variable $V(t)$, being from 0 to 2, is there a way I can tell Mathematica this directly, without me calculating the values of t and then using those to plot?

Comment: Post sample code.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Right, well like I said above that's going to take me a long time, at least an hour. But you are probably right that the problem warrants a more specific approach rather than general ideas on what to do. It's almost 2am here now though, so I guess I'll get back to it tomorrow and write some sample code. Would it be better to delete the question for now, and repost it tomorrow with the added code?

Comment: You might consider sampling the functions on an exponential scale: i.e. something like `t -> PowerRange[0.01, 10^21, 10]`, and using `ListPlot` instead. See what this gives you and then refine the grid as needed. As for the last question, I'll think on it.

Comment: @march That does make sense, and would probably work. Now I just have to figure out how to draw a parametric plot using listplot!

Comment: Oh, that's straightforward: `ListPlot[Table[{V[t], I[t]}, {t, PowerRange[0.01, 10^21, 10]}]]`.

Comment: @march That's giving me 'is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers' errors, but I guess I could easily resolve that in the morning, when I'm back to thinking clearly.

Comment: Well, I might have a typo in there, because I didn't test it, but I think you get the idea of how it would work. In addition, you can't use `I` as a variable name since it is reserved as the symbol for the complex unit. Finally, `PowerRange` was introduced in V10, so if you're working before V10, you won't have that function and you'll have to develop the code in a slightly different way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35570/discussion-between-user129412-and-march).

Comment: @march Yeah it was a mistake on my end, the output of the functions was in curly brackets so I had to do something about that. All in all it does work, but the only issue is that it is very dense in the left half of the plot, and very sparse in the right side, which makes sense due to how it samples of course. So perhaps I'll think a little bit more about maybe getting ParametricPlot to sample in a more clever way. Or I just have it calculate using powers of 1.0001, which takes ages but does give a smooth curve. Feels dirty though.

Comment: I have another thought, directly related to my first, that might allow you to still use `ParametricPlot`. Do something like `ParametricPlot[{v[Exp[t] - 1], i[Exp[t] - 1]}, {t, 0, 50}]`.